# What's fastest: iPhone 4 tethering with bluetooth, usb or the new hotspot feature?

Tags: iphone, wifi, bluetooth, tethering

I'm going to use the internet on a MacBook 5,2 and I have an iPhone 4 with iOS 4.3.1 and it's jailbroken (and using TetherMe), if it makes any differences.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fastest to slowest:

1. USB
2. WiFi hotspot
3. Bluetooth

Keep in mind the power draw of the options. From most battery efficient to least:

1. USB (It helps that it's also charging at the same time.)
2. Bluetooth
3. WiFi

Answer (score 1):

Bluetooth with iPhone's specifications has a max. throughput of 3 MBit/s. So this could be a bottleneck if you get higher 3G speeds.